# Failed to load module script because of MIME type

Tags: javascript, module, three.js, gltf

**Error on Chrome Console:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

I imported Three.js as type="module" and this error occurs. What's the problem? I looked up other posts, but it doesn't work.

The three.module.js file is in the same directory as my html file. Below is the full text of my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>gltfExample01</title>
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
    <div id="WebGL-output"></div>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
        
        var scene;
        var camera;
        var renderer;

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            scene.add(camera);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

            renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

            camera.position.x = -30;
            camera.position.y = 40;
            camera.position.z = 30;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // add the output of the renderer to the html element
            document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load(
                // resource URL
                './scene01.gltf',
                // called when the resource is loaded
                function ( gltf ) {

                    scene.add( gltf.scene );

                    gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
                    gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
                    gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
                    gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
                    gltf.asset; // Object

                }
            );

            function render() {
                // render using requestAnimationFrame
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            render();
        }
        window.onload = init

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you hosting your app? One of the servers mentioned in https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally might help to solve the issue.

Comment: I used node.js http server on the site you sent me and my question was solved. But another problem has arisen, so I will post a new question. Thx! :)